# Unable to retrieve the data from datastax having timestamp field

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I'm having the below table in the keyspace `myks`

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS myks.users (
    user_name text,
    email text,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_name)
);
```

Below is the model class

```
@Table(value = "users")
public @Data class Users{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column("user_name")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT)
    private String user_name;

    @Column("email")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT)
    private String email;

    @Column("created_at")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
    private Timestamp created_at;

    @Column("updated_at")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
    private Timestamp updated_at;
}
```

Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, String> {
}
```

Inserted the below values into the table

```
Users users = new Users();
LocalDateTime ldt_created = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime ldt_updated = ldt_created.plus(1000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
Timestamp ts_created = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt_created);
Timestamp ts_updated = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt_updated);
users.setUser_name(krishna");
users.setEmail("krishna@gmail.com");
users.setCreated_at(ts_created);
users.setUpdated_at(ts_updated);
usersRepository.save(users);
```

It got saved in the table but while retrieving the data it is throwing the below exception

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Date] to type [java.sql.Timestamp]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CQL's `timestamp` type is mapped into `java.util.Date` Java type, so you need to use it instead of `Timestamp`. See [CQL to Java mapping table](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) for this & other types.

You can also use so-called optional codecs (an additional dependency) to map `timestamp` into other Java types, such as, `Instant`. See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#jdk-8) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` is no longer used in driver 4.X `java-driver-mapper-processor` version. `Java.time.Instant` is used instead.
Mapping in `java.util.Date` doesn't work anymore, and throws exception:
`Field: expiration_date, Entity Type: java.util.Date, CQL type: TIMESTAMP`

So actual solution is to use `Java.time.Instant` for 4.X, and `java.util.Date` for 3.X.